# Как называется контрол для выбора меток?

Tags: wpf, gui

Как называется контрол для выбора меток (в частности на Stackoverflow)? У него ведь должно быть общее название. В частности интересует подобный контрол для WPF

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: может это то, что вы ищите: https://blog.pixelingene.com/2010/10/tokenizing-control-convert-text-to-tokens/

Comment: @S.Kost может и оно... очень похоже. Щас буду разбираться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Название сему чуду - TagControl.
К примеру - [infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/products/wpf/menus/tag-cloud).
Так же есть пример использования и написания кастомного контрола и на [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167809/how-can-i-create-a-tagging-control-similar-to-evernote-in-wpf)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]